# HttpURLConnection connect() , getInputStream() , getContent() , HttpGet

Tags: java, android, networking, httpurlconnection, http-get

I use the class HttpURLConnection , but Iam confused with some methods

assume the HttpURLConnection object name is "c"

1. removing c.connect() will result in a success connection and it will retrieve the connection result without any problem
2. the output of c.getInputStream() and (InputStream) c.grtContent() are identical , so what is the difference betqween them
3. using HttpGet will reach the same approach as HttpURLConnection  , so what is the difference between the two methods
4. what are the extra benefits for HttpURLConnection on URLConnection

   c = (HttpURLConnection) (URL).openConnection();
   c.connect(); //adding or removing makes the same result , so what is the usage of this method
   InputStream stream= c.getInputStream();
   InputStream stream2 = (InputStream) c.getContent();
   //stream and stream2 are identical , so what is the differece between getInputStream() and getContent()

   //============================

   HttpGet c= new HttpGet(url);
   HttpResponse response = c.execute(httpGet)
   InputStream stream3 = response.getEntity().getContent();
   //also stream3 is the same as stream & stream2 ; so how dose it different between HttpGet & HttpURLConnection

Comment: Don't put your question in code comments. Put it into English sentences outside the code where it can be seen.

Comment: Done @EJP ......

Answer (score 1):

From Android documentation:

> [`HttpURLConnection` is] A `URLConnection` with support for HTTP-specific features.

For instance, from an `HttpURLConnection` you can retrieve the HTTP method or the HTTP status code, which are HTTP-specific.

The `URLConnection` class, instead, is:

> The abstract class URLConnection is the superclass of all classes that represent a communications link between the application and a URL

The normal usage is:

1. Create a `URL` object
2. Get a `URLConnection` by calling `url.openConnection()`. The returned object can be casted to an `HttpURLConnection`
3. get an `InputStream` by calling the `connection.getInputStream()` method
4. <strike>Close the connection (`disconnect()` method)</strike> (see @EJP comments)

Concerning the `connect()` method, from the Oracle documentation:

> You are not always required to explicitly call the connect method to initiate the connection. Operations that depend on being connected, like `getInputStream`, `getOutputStream`, etc, will implicitly perform the connection, if necessary.

The difference between the `HttpGet` and `HttpURLConnection` is that they belong to 2 different libraries, but functionally they are more or less the same (now `HttpGet` has been deprecated and removed, so you won't find it in the standard Android APIs)

Comment: 4. Close the connection by closing the input stream. `disconnect()` has implications for connection-pooling and is not normally used.

Comment: Actually the documentation suggests to disconnect when you're done with reading. "Once the response body has been read, the HttpURLConnection should be closed by calling disconnect().". The thing you mention sound similar to a bug that was present in old Android versions (before 2.2): "Prior to Android 2.2 (Froyo), this class had some frustrating bugs. In particular, calling close() on a readable InputStream could poison the connection pool"

Comment: That documentation doesn't agree with the Oracle documentation, which makes it wrong.

Comment: Sorry, you are right! I think that's not good at all that Android documentation suggests to do a wrong thing

Comment: and what is the difference between , c.getInputStream() and (InputStream) c.grtContent() >> both obtained the same result

Comment: The `getInputStream()` returns the `InputStream` from which you can read the bytes of the response. The `getContent()`, instead, returns a Java `Object` by reading the response's bytes and converting them to an object, based on the MIME type and on the available `ContentHandler`. If you don't define any `ContentHandler`, maybe it returns the `InputStream`